# KDB: apply function to all values in a dictionary

Tags: string, function, dictionary, kdb

I have a dictionary with different prefixes corresponding to different keys. I want to append and pre-prend strings to each value in the dictionary.

For example:

```
filePrefixes: `QCentral`QWest`QEast!("GLO_CCEUML_CSFBSL_";"GLO_CCALML_CSFBSL_";"GLO_CCAPML_CSFBSL_")
```

And I want to pre-pend the folderPath and append the dateFormat and file extension ".csv".

So the dictionary should look like this:

```
filePrefixes: `QCentral`QWest`QEast!("..\..\code\products\Q\ShortLocator2\Request Files\1\GLO_CCEUML_CSFBSL_20181203_1948.csv";"..\..\code\products\Q\ShortLocator2\Request Files\1\GLO_CCALML_CSFBSL_20181203_1948.csv";"..\..\code\products\Q\ShortLocator2\Request Files\1\GLO_CCAPML_CSFBSL_20181203_1948.csv")
```

I did something like this. Not sure if there is a better way to do this:

```
  filename: (value filePrefixes),\:(dateFormat,".csv");
  filePaths: string[folderPath],/:(filename);
  filePrefixes:(key filePrefixes)!(filePaths);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values can be modified directly in the dictionary if that helps. Making some assumptions for `dateFormat` and `folderPath` based on your sample code:

```
dateFormat:"20181203_1948";
folderPath:"..\\..\\code\\products\\Q\\ShortLocator2\\Request Files\\1\\"
```

This can be combined with the steps you provided above without extracting the values:

```
q)show filePrefixes:folderPath,/:filePrefixes,\:dateFormat,".csv"
QCentral| "..\\..\\code\\products\\Q\\ShortLocator2\\Request Files\\1\\GLO_CCEUML_CSFBSL_20181203_1948.csv"
QWest   | "..\\..\\code\\products\\Q\\ShortLocator2\\Request Files\\1\\GLO_CCALML_CSFBSL_20181203_1948.csv"
QEast   | "..\\..\\code\\products\\Q\\ShortLocator2\\Request Files\\1\\GLO_CCAPML_CSFBSL_20181203_1948.csv"
```

Essentially the values act like a list, with some restrictions that are briefly discussed in the [dictionaries](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/5_Dictionaries/#515-dictionary-vs-list) section in Q for mortals.